# Overpass API: Get all public transport stops with a certain name

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm using the Overpass API to query OpenStreetMap for bus stops with a certain name near a specified location:

```
http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];node["name"="CITY"];node["around"="15000"];node["name"="STOP_NAME"]["highway"="bus_stop"];out;
```

Now I need to expand this query: I don't only want get all bus stops named `STOP_NAME` near `CITY`, but also tram stops (`railway=tram`) and subway stops (`railway=subway`) matching `STOP_NAME`.

I tried this, but it still only returns bus stops (and includes redundant information):

```
http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];node["name"="CITY"];(node(around:15000)["name"="STOP_NAME"]["highway"="bus_stop"];node(around:15000)["name"="STOP_NAME"]["railway"="tram_stop"];node(around:15000)["name"="STOP_NAME"]["railway"="subway_stop"];);(._;>;);out;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find another way of combining the criteria without redundancy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by including even more redundant information into the request URL: For each public transport type, I'm now repeating the "city node" and "around node".

I don't believe this is the best solution, but it's working well:

```
http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];node["name"="CITY"];node(around:15000)["name"="STATION"]["highway"="bus_stop"];node["name"="CITY"];node(around:15000)["name"="STATION"]["railway"~"tram_stop|station|subway"];out;
```